# how can a file upload / download operation be cancelled without terminating the thread that performs this operation?

Tags: java, multithreading, download, apache-commons, thread-abort

My code calls an API method that downloads a file from the internet. Because the download can take a large amount of time, I would like to provide the user with the ability to cancel the download if they close the window that shows the progress bar while a background thread handles the file download.

I'm not sure I have any control over the code called by the API method, so I'm assuming that I don't have an option to signal this code that the download operation needs to be cancelled.

If this assumption is correct, how do I terminate the file download operation on user request without having to abort/interrupt or otherwise terminate the background thread that performs the actual file download?

Comment: if you have access to the socket, just close it and it will throw an exception to the thread, else I suggest you run it by a process, that contains two thread(cancel listener, and download file), which the file download file is daemon, for any cancel method just signal the cancel thread, then cancel thread just finishes its job that causes file download killed silently something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17577908/java-why-is-this-code-not-working-infinite-loop/17580110#17580110)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would expect a properly-designed file download method to be interruptible. So you need to interrupt the thread in which the download is being done, which should cancel the download (the method should throw an InterruptedException).

Once you have caught the exception from the downloading thread, you can then decide what to do, for example wait for a new file download to be submitted (i.e. not exit).

Comment: am I right in assuming that the apache commons file download methods are interruptible?

Comment: @JSmith Do they throw InterruptedException? if they do then you can safely assume they are. And it is fairly easy to test anyway. If they don't there is probably a workaround (for example by closing the connection from another thread).