# Reading lines of input from user using SCANNER

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I have a program that needs to read lines of input. It needs to be many lines at once. For example:

---

As I enter my time machine or
maybe not,
I wonder whether free will exists?
I wonder whether free will exists
maybe not
as I enter my time machine or.

---

That all gets entered at one time by the user. I was trying to use .hasNextLine() method from Scanner class, but it is not returning false.... it waits for input again. Ive been looking around for a solution and it appears that .hasNextLine() waits for input, but i do not know what alternative to use. Any suggestions? The actual code looks like:

```
while(input.hasNextLine());
        {
            line += input.nextLine();
        }
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Why not just use `hasNext()`?

Comment: @Prateek not effective

Comment: this [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17577908/java-why-is-this-code-not-working-infinite-loop/17580110#17580110) may help.

Comment: @user2511414 can you explain why `hasNext()` is not effective?

Comment: because it blocks, and always returns `true` about `System.in` direction. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNext%28%29 @Prateek

Comment: Oh That..Thanks for pointing to the documentation :) I was concerned about why this would be ineffective for this particular case. I used it in sample code on my system and it worked just fine.

Comment: @Prateek in java the default `System.in` directive is kinda endless stream. so are you agree now that it doesn't work?!

Comment: so.... what should I use instead? That is the problem I have. hasNext() is not seeing the end

Comment: @Prateek C'mon dude you are talking about a specific protocol where user enters `STOP`, assume that system needs to give up reading from user if there is no input after 10(for example) seconds, so the problem is that thread is blocked by some I/O operation, and you cannot even kill the thread unless user flush the buffer.

Comment: @NickCarfagno one solution(not recommended) is that after the timeout, a `Robot` just trigger `Enter` key that causes flushing the buffer, and I think the best approach is using key event, you may need utilize `JConsole` or `jNativeHook`

Comment: Again mine is not a general solution. Just a minimal solution for the problem. And you are right about it being constrained with STOP as terminating condition

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you should use some sort of "stop" sequence meaning when the user enters a particular character sequence, it will break out the loop. It might look something like:

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    final String stopSequence = "/stop";
    final Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
    String input = reader.nextLine();
    while(!input.equalsIgnoreCase(stopSequence)){
        //process input
        input = reader.nextLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: input = reader.nextLine(); keeps asking for input. It goes all the way through, but then it stops and waits for input without exiting the while Loop.

Comment: @NickCarfagno It breaks out the loop due to the sentinel. I don't understand what you are trying to say.